# I'm running into an error of 'split' for nil:NilClass in ruby even though it was just working

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, file-io, nomethoderror

I was working on some code that I'm having a pretty tough time figuring out and then out of no where this error showed up saying:

```
in `process_data': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

So I undid the changes I made and it popped up again and again and I don't have the slightest clue as to what is causing it?
Code

```
class HiScore
    attr_reader :hiscore

    def initialize
        @hiscore = if File.exist?('hiscore.txt')
            read_file
        else
            build_new
        end
    end

    def show
        puts "Top 5 Scores"
        @hiscore.each do |r|
          puts r.each { |p| p }.join(" ")
        end
    end

    def build_new
        Array.new(5) {[1000, '--']}
        write_file()
    end

    def read_file()
        puts "read_file"
        #File.open('hiscore.txt', 'r') #{|f| f.each_line.map{|l| l.chomp!.split(',')}}\
        @hiscore = File.read("hiscore.txt").chomp!
        process_data(@hiscore)
    end

    def process_data(instance)
        @hiscore = @hiscore.split(",").to_a
        @hiscore = @hiscore.each_slice(2).to_a
    end

    def check(score)
        @hiscore.sort!{|s1, s2| s1[0] <=> s2[0]}
        max = @hiscore[4][0].to_i
        if score > max
            puts "Sorry no top score for you."
        else
            add_name(@score.to_s)
            # @hiscore.each do |row|
              # p row[0] do |column|
                  # puts column[0].to_i  
              # end
            # end
        end
    end

    def add_name(score)
        puts "You made it into the Top 5!"
        print "Enter your name: "
        @name = gets.chomp!.to_s
        @hiscore.push([score, @name]).sort!{|s1, s2| s1[0] <=> s2[0]}.pop
        #@hiscore = @scoreList
        #@hiscore = @scoreList
        write_file()

    end

    def write_file()
        File.open('hiscore.txt', 'w') do |f|
        @hiscore.each {|array| f.puts array.join(',')}
            #print "#{@hiscore}"
        end
    end

end

def start
    play = true
    while play == true
        num_guesses = 0
        answer = rand(1..1000)
        puts answer

        @game.show

        loop do
            print "Type in your guess: "
            guess = gets.chomp.to_i

            num_guesses += 1 
            unless guess == answer 
                message = if guess > answer 
                    "Too high"
                else
                    "Too low"
                end
                puts message 
            else
                puts "You got it!"
                puts "It took you #{num_guesses} guesses."
                @score = num_guesses
                @game.check(@score)

                break
            end
        end
        print "Would you like to play again? (y/n): "
        again = gets.chomp!
        if again == 'n'
            play = false
            puts "Ok, Bye!"
            exit
        elsif again == 'y'
            play = true
        end
    end
end

puts "I'm thinking of a random number from 1 to 1000"
puts "Can you guess it?"
@game = HiScore.new()
start()
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct cause for the error is that the `@hiscore` variable is `nil` in the `process_data` method when trying to be `split`-ed.

I guess that the underlying error might be the following line in the `read_file` method:

```
@hiscore = File.read("hiscore.txt").chomp!
```

According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp-21), the `chomp!` method **returns `nil` when it makes no modifications to the string**, i.e. when it does not strip off any newline characters from the end of the string. You probably want to use `chomp` instead which simply returns the original string if it has no newline at the end.

Comment: Thank you, I was so flustered before this came up I didn't even consider that being the the case.

Answer (score 0):

It may also throw error, if "hiscore.txt" has values already comma separated and you are attempting to split it again with "," delimiter.

"@hiscore" is instance variable to the function read_file, so scope will be limited to that function itself. In "process_data(instance)" function if you use instance inplace of "@hiscore" and that variable has right data then it will process correctly.